# nifi: which property should we add sql condition in querydatabasetable?

Tags: apache-nifi

i am using QueryDatabaseTable processor in nifi-1.3 version. i have successfully connected with Mysql database.
the table i use is, User which has columns such as user_id,name,email,gender.

```
TableName: User
Columns To Return: User_id, Email
Maximum Value Columns: user_id
```

with the above properties, i could successfully fetch the table with the columns (user_id,email) with the incremental records of user_id.

now i want to add some additional condition to the query. 
suppose, simple condition "where gender='Male'".

as given in documentation https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html , we can add additional where clause properties.

hence, i have added property in QueryDatabaseTable processor like below,

```
property  -   value
WHERE     -   gender='Male'
```

but it does not work.

any help on this.

how to add additional conditional clause in QueryDatabaseTable and also how to debug this processor what query has run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should put gender = 'Male' in the property called "Additional Where Clause", instead of adding new properties.

Comment: in QueryDatabaseTable processor, there is no property named "Additional Where Clause"